# Scala Anorm Why is scala complaining about result not having a trait?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm, playframework-2.1

I haven't seen anywhere this is done but I have the following:

```
abstract class Player { val user_id: Long }
case class AlivePlayer(user_id: Long, target_id: Long) extends Player
case class DeadPlayer(user_id: Long) extends Player

def getPlayers(game: Game):Option[List[Player]] = DB.withConnection { implicit connect =>
  SQL(
    """
      SELECT * FROM game_participants WHERE game_id = {game_id})
    """
  ).on(
    'game_id -> game.id
  ).as(Game.participantParser *)
}
```

In this case, I get an compiler error with the following message

```
error: type mismatch;  found   : anorm.ResultSetParser[List[Product with Serializable with models.Player]]  required: anorm.ResultSetParser[Option[List[models.Player]]]
).as(Game.participantParser *)
```

Why is it not sufficient for me to specify the return type solely as `Option[List[Player]]`?

Comment: Could you share the definition of the `participantParser` method?

Answer (score 1):

Given the error message, it sounds that `Game.participantParser` is not returning an `Option[List[Player]]` but `List[Player]`. IMHO, `getPlayers` should just return a `List[Player]` that may be empty.

If you want to return an `Option[]`, your will have to add `Some(...)` in front of your list  or just return `None` if the list is empty.

And as said in the comments, without the `Game.participantParser` definition it is not possible to help you furthermore.

Hope this helps.